# Grevisse, prescritivist?

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq

From the FAQ

> **Prescriptif ou descriptif ?** C'est au goût de chacun. Certains préfèrent citer le Dictionnaire de l'Académie et Grevisse, d'autres le Trésor de la langue française et Google Ngrams.

I always though that Grevisse was the one who made the most popular descriptive grammar of French.  This opinion seems to be shared by the authors of the Wikipedia article on the [Bon Usage](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) :

> Le Bon Usage (dit « Le Grevisse ») est une grammaire descriptive du français, publiée pour la première fois en 1936 par Maurice Grevisse, et périodiquement mise à jour depuis.

Comment: I agree, that's a bug. Can you suggest a well-known prescriptive grammar?

Comment: @Gilles, no. I'm unable to suggest any other French grammar, prescriptivist or descriptive.

Comment: @Gilles Bescherelle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bon, ça fait trop longtemps que ça traîne, donc j'ai remplacé Grevisse par Bescherelle ([proposé par Evpok](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/grevisse-prescritivist/357#comment651_352)) comme exemple d'ouvrage prescriptif, même si on ne peut pas dire que beaucoup de gens le citent ici. Si quelqu'un a une meilleure proposition, merci de répondre ici.

Answer (score 0):

I agree Grevisse is descriptive. At the very least he sure is a whole lot more than the Academy (which he pretty regularly lambasts about its dictionary's failings too). I'm not sure why the "prescriptive" labels come from, besides the fact there aren't that many extensive descriptive grammars in English OR French.